# Help with rigging a character with wide range of motion

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

Is there a rigging "technique" for characters with wide range of movement (like spiderman) without having the mesh deform and spaz out?

I downloaded a Deadpool model and have spent almost a week trying different bone positioning as well as spending countless hours on weight painting, but in the end he couldn't even reach for his sword on his back without his elbow being mangled into his arm and shoulder looking like stalagmites.

Comment: nice, phrasing. You need weight painting and possibly more verts.

Comment: You might want to consider using corrective shape keys. I've used them to bend stiff clothing and for facial animation. I've also seen videos of people using this to flex the muscles on the models.

Comment: @FranciscoChavez-Tejeda: Thanks, I'll look into it. Will it also help fix the stretching of the texture while posing?

Comment: Using a [mesh deform modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Mesh_Deform) might help. It works a bit like a lattice but you use a custom made low poly mesh object. The [sintel or sintel lite model](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/7093) uses mesh deform modifiers.